# For gcc in the -fsanitize option, how to use ‘address’ and ‘leak’ together?

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

gcc ver is 5.4.0

I want to use it like ：-fsanitize=address,leak

OK?

Comment: leak detection is supposed to be included in the address sanitizer.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Actually I think this is not the case for older (circa 4.8) releases where LSan and ASan were not yet integrated. See [this comment](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/699#issuecomment-290479274) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass both `-fsanitize=address` and `-fsanitize=leak` (as separate program arguments) to `gcc`. Read the chapter on [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and the section on [Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).

Consider also using the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) program.

Don't forget to compile *all* your code with `-Wall -Wextra -g` (and perhaps even `-g3`).

Comment: gcc's doc for older releases clearly states that -fsanitize=leak is useless if you have -fsanitize=address.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Could you provide more details? I think ASan and LSan were not integrated in older GCC releases.

Comment: Another option is to pass `-fsanitize=address,leak`.

Comment: -fsanitize=address will come with leak sanitizer. There is no need to specify leak sanitizer if you do not want to use it as a stand-alone. [Reference](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer).

Comment: Anyway even if address sanitizer include leak sanitizer this explanation is useful because you can be struggle with invoking other sanitizers like bounds, alignment etc. in one command